# sysrq-trigger doesn't accept parameter 'g'

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging, kgdb

I'm trying to debug the kernel. But I couldn't trigger kgdb with `echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, it just prints help message.

[image]

I have enabled kernel debugging, kgdb over serial, frame pointer etc.

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
```

What could be missing? The kernel version is 2.6.32.1, running CentOS 5 in KVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like setting `kgdboc` parameters in boot options worked, not sure why.

(I'm using libvirtd)

Comment: I had the same problem -- it turned out to be an error in `extlinux.conf` which caused the `kgdboc` boot option to not be passed.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://fatalfeel.blogspot.com/2013/09/kgdb-eclipse-debug-kernel-on-imx6.html) blogpost (in Chinese):

1. In the uboot header

```bsh
#define CONFIG_BOOTARGS_COMMON          "earlyprintk console=ttyS0,115200 kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 rootwait nprofile_irq_duration=on "
```

2. In defconfig

```bsh
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y     //make sure open it  
CONFIG_CONSOLE_POLL=y    //after CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE_CONSOLE=y  
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y  
CONFIG_FTRACE=y  
CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER=y  
CONFIG_KGDB=y  
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
```

3. After reboot

```bsh
echo ttyS0 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc  
show -> KGDB: Registered I/O driver kgdboc  

echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger  
show -> sysrq: SysRq : DEBUG  
KGDB: Entering KGDB
```